# How to make the selection tag upload data to sql with php

Tags: php, html, sql, wampserver

I'm a beginner on coding and I've been working on this type of project in which I want to insert data to an SQL server with PHP, so what I'm struggling with is the part where I want to insert data and I want to take the select tags objects into variables, I've been getting Undefined Index so if you could help I'd be very grateful.

HTML Code:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" class="puo" id="modeloPU" name="Nmod" style="width: 
9.6%">
    <select class="puo" id="familiaSPU" name="Nfam">
        <option value="-1   "></option>
        <option value="0" style="font-style: italic; color:grey">indefinido</option>
        <option value="1">ENFRIADORES</option>
        <option value="2">FROSTER</option>              
        <option value="3">CONGELADORES</option>             
        <option value="4">MIRAGE</option></select>
    <select class="puo puh" id="odpSPU" name="Nodp">
        <option value="-1"></option>
        <option value="0" style="font-style: italic; color:grey">indefinido</option>
        <option value="1">HORIZONTAL</option>
        <option value="2">VERTICAL</option></select>
    <select class="puo puh" id="tdcSPU" name="Ntdc">
        <option value="-1"></option>
        <option value="0" style="font-style: italic; color:grey">indefinido</option>
        <option value="1">CLIENTE PARTICULAR</option>
        <option value="2">VALIDADOS</option>
        <option value="3">DEFINIDOS</option>
        <option value="4">ESTÁNDAR</option></select>
    <select class="puo puh" id="clienteSPU" name="Ncliente">
        <option value="-1"></option>
        <option value="0" style="font-style: italic; color:grey">indefinido</option>                            
        <option value="1">CBC</option>
        <option value="2">COCA-COLA</option>
        <option value="3">FASA</option>
        <option value="4">FLORIDA</option>
        <option value="5">HOSHISAKI</option>
        <option value="6">JALEEL</option></select>
    <select class="puo puh" id="voltajeSPU" name="Nvoltaje">
        <option value="-1"></option>
        <option value="0" style="font-style: italic; color:grey">indefinido</option>                
        <option value="1">110V(50Hz - 60Hz)</option>
        <option value="2">140V(50Hz - 60Hz)</option>
        <option value="3">220V(50Hz - 60Hz)</option></select>
    <select class="puo puh" id="gradoSPU" name="Ngrado">
        <option value="-1"></option>
        <option value="0" style="font-style: italic; color:grey">indefinido</option>                
        <option value="1">C°</option>
        <option value="2">F°</option></select>
    <select class="puo puh" id="termostatoSPU" name="Ntermostato">
        <option value="-1"></option>
        <option value="0" style="font-style: italic; color:grey">indefinido</option>
        <option value="1">CAREL</option>
        <option value="2">COEL</option>
        <option value="3">ELSTAT</option>
        <option value="4">FULL GAUGE</option>
        <option value="5">SOLLATEK</option>
        <option value="6">WELLINGTON</option></select>
    <select class="puo puh" id="tdpSPU" name="Ntdp">
        <option value="-1"></option>
        <option value="0" style="font-style: italic; color:grey">indefinido</option>                
        <option value="1">PVP</option>
        <option value="2">PVPH</option>
        <option value="3">PS</option></select>
    <select class="puo puh" id="paisSPU" name="Npais">
        <option value="-1"></option>
        <option value="0" style="font-style: italic; color:grey">indefinido</option>                
        <option value="1">USA</option>
        <option value="2">Puerto Rico</option>
        <option value="3">Latino America</option></select>          
    <input type="submit" class="Boton" name="submit" id="AddButton" 
value="Agregar" style="box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24), 0 17px 
50px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19); cursor: pointer;">
</form>
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php   
include 'conn.php';
$myDate         = date('Y/m/d');    
$model          = $_POST['Nmod'];
$fam            = $_POST['Nfam'];
$orientacion    = $_POST['Nodp'];
$tdcliente      = $_POST['Ntdc'];
$cli            = $_POST['Ncliente'];
$volt           = $_POST['Nvoltaje'];
$grad           = $_POST['Ngrado'];
$termo          = $_POST['Ntermostato'];
$tdpuerta       = $_POST['Ntdp'];
$pai            = $_POST['Npais'];

$SQL = "INSERT INTO usuario (modelo ,familia ,odp ,tdc ,cliente ,voltaje ,
                            grado ,termostato, tdp, pais, fecha) 
                VALUES ('$model', '$fam', 
                        '$orientacion', '$tdcliente', '$cli', '$volt', 
                        '$grad', '$termo', '$tdpuerta', '$pai','$myDate')";
if ($conn->query($SQL) == TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} 
else {
    echo "Error: " . $SQL . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();                                 
?>
```

Comment: You need to specify you PHP-Script in the action-Attribute of your form

Comment: Are those in the same file?

Answer (score 0):

You get ***undefined index errors*** because the first time the form loads `$_POST` has not been created as the form has not yet been submitted but you are still running the code that references `$_POST`. You have to check that the form was actually submitted before attempting to use `$_POST`

There are a number of ways to do that and this is one

```
<?php   
include 'conn.php';

// has the form been submitted
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $myDate         = date('Y/m/d');    
    $model          = $_POST['Nmod'];
    $fam            = $_POST['Nfam'];
    $orientacion    = $_POST['Nodp'];
    $tdcliente      = $_POST['Ntdc'];
    $cli            = $_POST['Ncliente'];
    $volt           = $_POST['Nvoltaje'];
    $grad           = $_POST['Ngrado'];
    $termo          = $_POST['Ntermostato'];
    $tdpuerta       = $_POST['Ntdp'];
    $pai            = $_POST['Npais'];

    $SQL = "INSERT INTO usuario (modelo ,familia ,odp ,tdc ,cliente ,voltaje ,
                                grado ,termostato, tdp, pais, fecha) 
                    VALUES ('$model', '$fam', 
                            '$orientacion', '$tdcliente', '$cli', '$volt', 
                            '$grad', '$termo', '$tdpuerta', '$pai','$myDate')";
    if ($conn->query($SQL) == TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } 
    else {
        echo "Error: " . $SQL . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
    $conn->close();                                 
}
?>
```

> I do have to also mention that Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
>   Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
>   Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's